# Delphi/Excel - Worksheets not instantiated

Tags: excel, delphi, office-interop

Delphi RIO / Excel 2016.  I am using Delphi to start Excel, and then create a new spreadsheet, which I will later update....  I have done a good bit of coding with Delphi/Excel, and I am seeing behavior I don't believe I have seen before.  I create Excel, then do an ExcelApp.Worksheets.Add... to create a new worksheets.  As I have just started Excel, the Worksheets object is nil, and subsequently, I get an OLE Error (800A03EC) when I try to Add a new Worksheet.  If I step through the code, and RIGHT BEFORE the ExcelApp.Worksheets.Add line, I go to Excel, and do a File/New, so that there is an empty sheet displayed, my code works fine.  So the question is, when ExcelApp.Worksheets is nil, how do I instantiate it?  I could have swore that the 'Add' routine did that automatically.

```
function glib_TestExcel: Integer;
var
  myAPP: OleVariant;
  oExcel : ExcelApplication;
  thisSheet: _Worksheet;
begin
  if not Assigned(oExcel) then
  begin
    myAPP := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
    oExcel := IDispatch(myAPP) as ExcelApplication;

    oExcel.Visible[LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT] := True;
    oExcel.ScreenUpdating[LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT] := True;

    // THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE BELOW
     oExcel.Worksheets.Add(EmptyParam, EmptyParam,1, xlWorksheet, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT );

     // Get a handle to the new sheet and set the Sheet Name
     thisSheet := oExcel.ActiveSheet as _Worksheet;
     thisSheet.Name := 'New Sheet1';
     result := glib_SUCCESS;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: That was the culprit.  Submit as answer, and I will accept;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to create a `WorkBook` first, to host the `Worksheet`s.